# What do I do with the "files"?

Tags: 7

I have a pantheon account and a Drupal site installed on it. I wanted to work on my project via localhost, so I have the WAMP server setup, with the Drupal code and downloaded & imported the Drupal Database. However, I also have pantheon "files". What do I do with these files if I already have the code & database? I downloaded them to my computer in a zip file, but not sure what to do with them or where to put them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be the contents of your public file system, which will usually be placed at PATH_TO_DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/default/files